# Eclipse Reference Libraries

Tags: eclipse, reference, libraries

In Eclipse IDE, when I have created the Java Projects, I don't see the Referenced libraries. Is it that some settings might have changed? Or in Eclipse Mars it doesn't show? 
Since for some of my projects I needed the libraries, I had created a folder named, say Rsrcs, and added all the jar files to it.
How can I get the Referenced libraries folder by default when I create the projects?

Comment: did you try Ctrl + N  ==> Java Project ==> NEXT ==> Libraries -> Add External JARs?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem that I had was the Referenced Libraries was not checked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the 'Package Explorer' or 'Project Explorer' view open the view menu (click the small triangle at the top right of the view). Select the 'Show Referenced Libraries Node' menu item.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

**Right click on Project >> Show In >> Project Explorer**